# Building rosjava fails at task ':apache_xmlrpc_common:compileJava'

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm currently setting up an Ubuntu 11.10 with ROS Electric to use rosjava. The build tools are ant 1.8, maven 2.2 and rosws.

Installing rosjava as described link:[here](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/building.html) unfortunately fails at building the task ':apache_xmlrpc_common:compileJava' with error message:

> Building > :apache_xmlrpc_common:compileJava > Resolving dependencies ':apache:apache_xmlrpc_common:compileJava
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':apache_xmlrpc_common:compileJava'.

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

I've got no clue how to fix this; is there anything I missed?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Andreas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31800/building-rosjava-fails-at-task-%27:apache_xmlrpc_common:compilejava%27/) by [andreasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/1333/andreasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-04-14

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using "openjdk-7-jdk" try reverting back to "openjdk-6-jdk".  This resolved the issue for me.

---

Originally posted by [bblodget](https://answers.ros.org/users/1939/bblodget/) with karma: 73 on 2012-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-03-11**:
Removing openjdk-7 didn't work for me. Instead @SergioGutierrez's [solution](http://goo.gl/08Z1b) worked with [this version](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/rosandroid/commits/cc26f896f2f93a39d73a5eec4e8d8c4139e7fbc0) of rosandroid

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello again,

Problem solved, it had nothing to do with the build.gradle file, I was using the jre installed from ubuntu software center "OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime", the problem was gone when I installed gradle from apt "sudo apt-get install gradle", wich installs also the necessary java software like javac, after installing I only had to add at the end of the etc/bash.bashrc the JAVA_HOME to "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java", export the variable with "export JAVA_HOME", the PATH to "PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin", export the variable PATH "export PATH", and then all worked nicely.

Best regards.

---

Originally posted by [SergioGutierrez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2305/sergiogutierrez/) with karma: 86 on 2012-05-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6